# Wireshark showing no encryption in OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I have cipher BF-CBC uncommented in both server and client and wireshark is listening to tap0 but it is not showing any encryption. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenVPN is connected in this way:

```
 [you - tap0-]-- INTERNET --[-tap0 - server ]
```

The traffic between `you` and `tap0` is unencrypted, the same applies to `tap0` <> `server`. The traffic between both `tap0`s is encrypted.

`tap0` is connected through a physical network adapter, `eth0` for wired connections, `wlan0` for wireless connections. That would look like this:

```
 [ YOUR COMPUTER ]--wlan0-- INTERNET --eth0--[ SERVER ]
```

If you are using a wireless connection, you should listen on `wlan0` insteap of `tap0` using wireshark. You'll see traffic between UDP ports 1194, which is encrypted.

Don't worry, OpenVPN will use the BF-CBC cipher if the cipher is omitted. Uncommenting it implies using this BF-CBC cipher.